# I deployed React and spring boot into 2 different applications on heroku. How can i make them talk to each other

Tags: reactjs, spring-boot, heroku

I deployed react and spring boot into 2 separate Applications on Heroku.

React: https://sleepy-waters-86207.herokuapp.com/

Spring: https://boot-hheroku.herokuapp.com/

in react, i tried to fetch data via https://boot-hheroku.herokuapp.com/
it's blocked by CORS policy. How can i fix it?

in development, i change the proxy to "proxy": "http://localhost:8080",
it's not gonna work after i deployed React to heroku. I don't know what to do.

```
  hello = () => {
    fetch("https://boot-hheroku.herokuapp.com/api/hello")
      .then(response => response.text())
      .then(message => {
        this.setState({ message: message });
      });
  };
```

Comment: white list the frontend domain on your spring app: https://spring.io/guides/gs/rest-service-cors/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CORS policy is managed by the backend application, you need to allow that origin in your Rest API.

Basically it happens when you are trying to access to the backend from another domain that where is deployed the Rest Api mainly with POST, PUT, DELETE Http Methods, this is your case.

You need to allow the origin, it is your server where is deployed your front application with the code:

```
setAllowedOrigins
```

Here is an example about the configuration in Spring Boot:

```
@Bean
    CorsConfigurationSource corsConfigurationSource() {
        CorsConfiguration configuration = new CorsConfiguration();
        configuration.setAllowedOrigins(Arrays.asList("https://boot-hheroku.herokuapp.com"));
        configuration.setAllowedMethods(Arrays.asList("GET", "POST", "PUT", "DELETE", "HEAD", "OPTIONS"));
        configuration.setAllowedHeaders(Arrays.asList("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Access-Control-Allow-Origin",
                "Access-Control-Request-Method", "Access-Control-Request-Headers", "Origin",
                "Cache-Control", "Content-Type"));
        final UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource source = new UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource();
        source.registerCorsConfiguration("/**", configuration);
        return source;
    }
```